# laravel 8 Undefined variable: country_id

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

While using Eloquent: Relationships, I get this error: Undefined variable: country_id.

```
<div>
        <label for="country_id" class="form-label">country:</label>
        @foreach ( $countries as $country )
            <label for="country_id" class="form-label">
                {{ $profiles->$country_id->$country->name  }}
            </label>
        @endforeach
    </div>
```

this in ProfilesController : show function

```
/**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @param  \App\Models\profiles  $profiles
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(profiles $profiles, $id)
    {
        //
        $profiles = profiles::findOrFail($id);

        //$countries = countries::all();
        $countries = DB::table('countries')->pluck('name','id');
        //dd($countries);
        $languages = languages::all();

        return view('Profile.show', compact('profiles','countries','languages'));
    }
```

this models profiles

```
 /**
     * Relationship : belongsTo  To countries
     * Get the countries associated with the profiles.
     */
    public function countries()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(countries::class);
    }
```

this models countries

```
 /**
     * Relationship : One To One
     * Get the profiles that owns the countries.
     */
     public function profiles()
     {
         return $this->hasOne(profiles::class,'country_id');
     }
```

thank you

Comment: The error message means this code here: `$profiles->$country_id->...` - the variable `$country_id` is not set anywhere.

Comment: You are not even using the relationships.. you're looping over countries and somehow trying to access it with `$profile`.. Please read [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#introduction) more thorough.

Answer (score 2):

You are reading the country completely wrong:

There is a foreach where you loop the countries. so `$country` holds the country model. simply output like this :

```
<div>
        <label for="country_id" class="form-label">country:</label>
        @foreach ( $countries as $country )
            <label for="country_id" class="form-label">
                {{ $country->name  }}
            </label>
        @endforeach
    </div>
```

It also looks like your relationships are not correct. belongsTo is a 1-1 relation, you read it as a 1-many relationship. I would suggest reading the docs on the different Eloquent relationships.

Comment: hello Gert B (Trying to get property 'name' of non-object) and I fixed Trying to get property 'name' of non-object  other tables countries i have forge key in tables profiles thank you

Comment: You have multiple mistakes in this code: You get all countries as an array instead of using Eloquent ( `Country::get()` ) but i guess you only need the country from te profile? or do you need a select with all countries? You have a `profiles` model that should be `Profile`, same for `Language` instead of `languages` ... I would really suggest reading the docs for Laravel. If you use the naming conventions and use Eloquent, things will start working out of the box

Comment: You also create labels for all countries without inputs or selects, so i'm not sure what exactly you want to do

Comment: Hello @GertB  its do loop not selected name for tables countries try selected for tables countries by name, the profile's tables foreign key country_id

Answer (score 0):

I believe there an error with the dollar sign in the chained properties. Just remove the extra dollar signs.

This is the snippet with the wrong code fixed:

```
<div>
        <label for="country_id" class="form-label">country:</label>
        @foreach ( $countries as $country )
            <label for="country_id" class="form-label">
                {{ $country->name  }}
            </label>
        @endforeach
    </div>
```